# Technical term for social questions?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a (technical) term that can summarize "society" practical and in theory? Like when I say a country has its politics, education system and ... "society issues"?

Asked differently: is there a generic term for social questions like emancipation (women's lib) etc.? Sure this example can be political and educational but I'm looking for something just not political or educational.

**Edit:** Also I'd prefer if the term would sound educated, not too plain.

Thanks for any help!

*(I'm not native English and my English is around superficial, sorry :)*

Comment: do you mean "temporal" issues?  ("relating to worldly as opposed to spiritual affairs; secular.")

Comment: @JoeBlow With this Q I'm relating to the history of a country so I would go for secular. Is "spiritual affairs" a suggestion to paraphrase what I'm asking about?

Comment: In OP's context I'd just go with ***and other sociologiocal issues***. Most such issues (religion, equality, sexual standards, racial integration, etc.) are intimately interleaved with *political* and *educational* processes. Why would we expect a special word for all aspects of social organisation that aren't very closely related to either of those two? Offhand I can think of *popular entertainment* as being a big chunk, but even that is only a small part of the (ill-defined, and thus probably inherently nameless/unnameable) thing being envisaged here.

Comment: Right.  In a sense ... *"Asked differently: is there a generic term for social questions like emancipation (women's lib) etc.?"*  the answer is simply **political issues**.  What you're talking about is, simply, the "political issues" of the day.

Comment: "Society" it is, in a different (or broader) sense. Try *society* in the sentence and see how it sounds/ scans.

Comment: How about _culture_?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your suggestion, "sociological issues", sounds good indeed.

Comment: @Bitterblue: Note that my suggestion was ***other** sociological issues*, since it would include politics and education anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Societal may be the word you're looking for.